# Django Raw query usage

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am struggling to use the output of a raw query.  My code is as follows:

```
cursor.execute("select f.fixturematchday, u.teamselection1or2, u.teamselectionid,u.user_id from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection u where u.user_id = 349 and f.fixtureid = u.fixtureid and f.fixturematchday=6 order by u.teamselection1or2")
currentSelectedTeams = cursor.fetchone()

if not currentSelectedTeams:
    currentSelectedTeam1 = 0
    currentSelectedTeam2 = 0
else:
    currentSelectedTeam1 = currentSelectedTeams[0].teamselectionid
    currentSelectedTeam2 = currentSelectedTeams[1].teamselectionid
```

I get the following error:

```
currentSelectedTeam1 = currentSelectedTeams[0].teamselectionid
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'teamselectionid'
```

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance, Alan.

PS

In case it helps the result of my query in MySQL is as follows:

```
mysql> select f.fixturematchday, u.teamselection1or2, u.teamselectionid,u.user_id from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection u where u.user_id = 349 and f.fixtureid = u.fixtureid and f.fixturematchday=6 order by u.teamselection1or2;
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+
| fixturematchday | teamselection1or2 | teamselectionid | user_id |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+
|               6 |                 1 |              31 |     349 |
|               6 |                 2 |              21 |     349 |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are [using `cursor.fetchone()`](http://currentSelectedTeams%20=%20cursor.fetchone()) and iterating through the result expecting it to return multiple rows.

If you want the top 2 results, you might want to use [`fetchmany` and limit to 2 records instead](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).

This is what is happening under the hood:

Since you are fetching only one record, `currentSelectedTeams[0]` is actually returning the `fixturematchday` column, which it looks like is of type `long` and you are unable to access the attribute from it.

Another option would be to use the [pretty powerful `Django ORM`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/) to fetch this query result

EDIT:

If you really want to stick with `cursor` based implementation, try this:

```
cursor.execute("select f.fixturematchday, u.teamselection1or2, u.teamselectionid,u.user_id from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection u where u.user_id = 349 and f.fixtureid = u.fixtureid and f.fixturematchday=6 order by u.teamselection1or2 LIMIT 2")
#Note the LIMIT 2

currentSelectedTeams = cursor.fetchall()

if not currentSelectedTeams:
    currentSelectedTeam1 = 0
    currentSelectedTeam2 = 0
else:
    currentSelectedTeam1 = currentSelectedTeams[0].teamselectionid
    currentSelectedTeam2 = currentSelectedTeams[1].teamselectionid
```

Note that, in an edge case scenario, where only one row is returned, this implementation would fail. (You need to check for the cursor return length, etc.. )

If this were a django queryset implementation, it would look something like this:

```
qs = Fixture.objects.filter(..).values("fixturematchday", "userselection__ teamselection1or2", "userselection__teamselectionid", "userselection__userid")[:2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I know this is a simple sql example but I have some more advanced ones that are more efficient in the raw format than running it through django.  The query can only ever choose a maximum of two results so the fetchmany would not be required on this occasion.  Would there be a better way to return the results so I can utilise the results in the same way as a django queryset?

Comment: You need to understand the underlying issue, which is what i tried to point out in the answer. `fetchmany` takes an optional argument called `size` or if you add `limit 2` to your raw sql, you should be able to limit the response to 2 results max. Another option would be to look into `fetchall` - of course with the limit 2 clause

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand the point.  I have no issues with how many results are being returned.  I just need to understand how to access the results.  Apologies if I am missing something basic that relates to how to access the information.

Comment: Did you get a chance to read the entire answer ? especially thisone: `Since you are fetching only one record, currentSelectedTeams[0] is actually returning the fixturematchday column, which it looks like is of type long and you are unable to access the attribute from it.`

Comment: yes, i read the answer.  I obviously dont understand what is going on.  Do not worry, I will go away and re read the docs for the 1,000th time in the hope I can make sense of it.  It feels like this part should be so easy but is causing no end of stress.  I appreciate your time, many thanks, Alan.

Comment: It's really not the docs that are the problem. You fetched a single row, as `currentSelectedTeams`. Therefore `currentSelectedTeams[0]` is the first *column* of that row, not the first row in the result set. That column has an integer value; an integer does not have a `teamselectionid` attribute.

Comment: As karthkir says though, you shouldn't really be using raw queries here; this is not a complex query and should be done directly with the Django db layer.

Comment: Hello Daniel,  Not at any point did I imply the docs were the problem.  Simply my understanding.  I know get what my fundamentally error is.  Think it is definitely a case of spending too much time staring at my screen today.  As for the query being in SQL it is merely just a tester for this example as I have many more complex queries within raw sql that are already written and ready to go.  Many thanks to your both for you perseverance.